# Strange listing of new files by git status: new file: "\302\250"

Tags: git, macos

I'm getting a strange listing of new files when I run `git st` (git status) command from Mac (OSX El Capitain 10.11.2) command line:

```
new file:   "\302\250"
new file:   "js/\302\250"
```

These files are NOT shown by a regular `ls -l` in the command line, nor in Finder:

```
ls -l "\302\250"
ls: \302\250: No such file or directory
```

I've set all files to be visible by:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

Still can't see those files with anything but `git st` command.

Comment: try `ls -a` - anyway, maybe git can fix it for you? `git reset --hard`

Comment: For (much) more on file naming issues, see chapter 3, pages 48 through 52, of [this work in progress](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octal `302 250` corresponds to Unicode U+00A8, or DIAERESIS. This is the umlaut used in various European languages such as German (two dots above a character).

```
$ printf '\ua8' | od -to1
0000000   302 250
0000002
```

If you have a file like this, you should be able to get rid of it using:

```
rm $(printf '\302\250')
```

Comment: The fix is right (answer upvoted), but it's worth noting that U+00A8 is a non-combining diaeresis; the combining one is U+0308.

Comment: @torek Hm not sure how I pasted the name from the wrong codepoint... thanks for the comment, I've corrected the answer.